# ASP.NET MVC4 override OnAuthorization to allow whitelist of roles

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-4, authorization

I have an ASP.NET MVC4 site with two types of roles: Administrator and Partner.

Basically all access to the site requires a user to authenticated and have role Administrator.
Therefore I do this in FilterConfig.cs (called from Global.asax):

```
public class FilterConfig {
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters) {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute { Roles = "Administrator" }); // default deny
    }
}
```

For one controller however I want grant access to users with the Partner role but wihtout the Adminstrator role. I know I could do this by not using the global filter and instead set Authorize attributes on each Controller or Action, but I would like a white list approach instead where all acces by default requires "Administrator" role and then use some form of white listing.

I have tried using a controller where I override OnAuthorization like this:

```
public class MyController : Controller {
    protected override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
            var attributes = new List<AllowRolesAttribute>();
            attributes.AddRange(filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<AllowRolesAttribute>());
            attributes.AddRange(filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<AllowRolesAttribute>());
            foreach (var authorizationAttribute in attributes) {
                foreach (var role in authorizationAttribute.Roles.Split(',')) {
                    if (User.IsInRole(role))
                        return; // Skip authorization because user has one of the allowed roles.
                }
            }
        }
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
}
```

I then define the controller like this:

```
[AllowRoles(Roles = "Partner")]
public class HomeController : MyController
{
    ...
```

But this does not work. When I access this controller with a user with role "Partner" I can follow the code into the inner return statement, but the user is still redirected to the login page instead of being authorized. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're using Forms authentication or not. Possibly need something like this?

```
[AllowRoles(Roles = "Partner")]
public class HomeController : MyController
{     
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage( "User", false );
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: Yes I am using Forms auth. I want the AllowRoles attribute to have the  effect that access can be granted to certain controllers/actions for users with the roles given in the Roles parameters despite they are not having the Administrator role which is a global requirement.